# Array associativa multidimensional vários sub-níveis no C#

Tags: c#, array-multidimensional

Estou convertendo um sistema PHP/JS para C# e estou estacionado na parte de arrays. O aplicativo está quase finalizado, só falta essa parte que é a mais importante.

Eu já fiz umas centenas de buscas, já tentei entender tudo que li sobre arrays, lists e listTables mas tudo que encontrei tem uma ou duas dimensões e não consegui adaptar para mais dimensões de forma que eu consiga fazer a busca do mesmo jeito que faço no PHP, através de chaves associativas variáveis vindo das escolhas do usuário. O C# é muito diferente de todas as linguagens com que já trabalhei nesse sentido.

No PHP, a array está assim:

```
$mundo = [];
    $mundo["ori"] = [];
        $mundo["ori"]["norte"] = [];
            $mundo["ori"]["norte"]["Pais 1"] = [];
                $mundo["ori"]["norte"]["Pais 1"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["ori"]["norte"]["Pais 2"] = [];
                $mundo["ori"]["norte"]["Pais 2"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
                $mundo["ori"]["norte"]["Pais 2"][1] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
        $mundo["ori"]["sul"] = [];
            $mundo["ori"]["sul"]["Pais 3"] = [];
                $mundo["ori"]["sul"]["Pais 3"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
                $mundo["ori"]["sul"]["Pais 3"][1] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
                $mundo["ori"]["sul"]["Pais 3"][2] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["ori"]["sul"]["Pais 4"] = [];
                $mundo["ori"]["sul"]["Pais 4"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
                $mundo["ori"]["sul"]["Pais 4"][1] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["ori"]["sul"]["Pais 5"] = [];
                $mundo["ori"]["sul"]["Pais 5"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
    $mundo["oci"] = [];
        $mundo["oci"]["norte"] = [];
            $mundo["oci"]["norte"]["Pais 6"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["norte"]["Pais 6"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["oci"]["norte"]["Pais 7"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["norte"]["Pais 7"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
                $mundo["oci"]["norte"]["Pais 7"][1] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
        $mundo["oci"]["sul"] = [];
            $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 8"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 8"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 8"][1] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 9"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 9"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 10"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 10"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 11"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 11"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 12"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 12"][3] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 13"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 13"][2] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 14"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 14"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 14"][1] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
            $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 15"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 15"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 15"][1] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
```

É uma figuração modelo da real mas mantendo toda a estrutura de níveis e sub-níveis. Eu não queria mudar o esquema porque teria que mudar toda a estrutura. No PHP, faço a pesquisa através de variáveis que trazem os valores escolhidos pelo usuário. Por exemplo: em $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 14"][1], o usuário pesquisou por algo como **ocidente > sul > Nome do país > Nome da Cidade**. Na array real, são mais de 4.000 linhas no sub-nível **["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"]**. Obviamente, não escrevi tudo a mão. São dados de mais de 4.000 arquivos txt que eu varri com um glob(), no PHP, e retornei os 3 dados de cada um deles. No meu server, esses arquivos txt estão divididos em subpastas com a estrutura exata dos níveis/ sub-níveis da array. Por isso, é fácil fazer a leitura e retorno dos dados.

A minha pergunta, afinal, é: como seria a estrutura do código acima, em C#, para criar esse esquema de arrays? Pelo que vi, me parece que as Lists são mais indicadas. Mas, se tiver outra forma mais eficaz, será bem vinda, também.

**EDIT:** Supondo que eu tenho uma array em javaScript:

```
mundo = [];
        mundo["ori"] = [];
            mundo["ori"]["norte"] = [];
                mundo["ori"]["norte"]["Pais 1"] = [];
                    mundo["ori"]["norte"]["Pais 1"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
        mundo["oci"] = [];
            mundo["oci"]["sul"] = [];
                mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 3"] = [];
                    mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 3"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
```

Eu tenho um form onde o usuário escolhe/ digita os dados e pego esses dados no js:

```
oo = $("#lado").val();
ns = $("#regiao").val();
pa = $("#pais").val();
```

Busco os dados na array:

```
v1 = mundo[oo][ns][pa][0]["Valor 1"];
v2 = mundo[oo][ns][pa][0]["Valor 2"];
v3 = mundo[oo][ns][pa][0]["Valor 3"];
```

Para mudar isso para PHP, apenas acrescento um cifrão nas variáveis e mudo o jQuery para $_POST ou $_GET:

```
$mundo = [];
        $mundo["ori"] = [];
            $mundo["ori"]["norte"] = [];
                $mundo["ori"]["norte"]["Pais 1"] = [];
                    $mundo["ori"]["norte"]["Pais 1"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];
        $mundo["oci"] = [];
            $mundo["oci"]["sul"] = [];
                $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 3"] = [];
                    $mundo["oci"]["sul"]["Pais 3"][0] = ["Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"];

$oo = $_POST["lado"];
$ns = $_POST["regiao"];
$pa = $_POST["pais"];

$v1 = $mundo[oo][ns][pa][0]["Valor 1"];
$v2 = $mundo[oo][ns][pa][0]["Valor 2"];
$v3 = $mundo[oo][ns][pa][0]["Valor 3"];
```

O que estou tentando entender, é como fazer essa mudança na estrutura da array para pegar o resultado no C#, mantendo ela como associativa para não precisar alterar mais umas estruturas de linhas de códigos para adaptar. Esse é meu primeiro trabalho em C#. Consegui fazer as outras partes quase tudo sozinho e umas poucas coisas, consegui pesquisando, sem precisar perguntar. Só essa parte de arrays que é muito diferente. Parece que tem que dar imports, criar várias classes, usar vários gets e sets...

**EDIT 2:**

O JSON dessa array ficaria assim:

```
{"ori":
    {"norte":
        {"Pais 1":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 2":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"],
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ]
    },
    "sul":
        {"Pais 3":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"],
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"],
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 4":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"],
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 5":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ]
    }
},
"oci":
    {"norte":
        {"Pais 6":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 7":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"],
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ]
    },
    "sul":
        {"Pais 8":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"],
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 9":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 10":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 11":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 12":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 13":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 14":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"],
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ],
        "Pais 15":[
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"],
            ["Valor 1","Valor 2","Valor 3"]
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

Até consegui criar uma array parecida desse jeito:

```
string[,,,] mundo =
{
    {
        {
            {
                {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}, {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}, {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}
            },
            {
                {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}, {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}, {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}
            }
        },
        {
            {
                {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}, {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}, {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}
            },
            {
                {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}, {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}, {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}
            },
            {
                {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}, {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}, {"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"}
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Só que tem dois problemas: não encontrei uma forma de colocar ela associativa, de forma que eu possa referenciar os níveis através dos nomes tipo **mundo["ori", "sul", "bra", 0]** ou **mundo["ori"]["sul"][bra"][0]** que faria mais sentido por ter nomes e index e não dá para ter números diferentes de sub-níveis. Na prática, minha array começa com dois níveis: "ori" e "oci". Cada um desses níveis, se divide em dois sub-níveis: "norte" e "sul". A partir daqui, complica porque cada "norte" e cada "sul" pode ter números diferentes de sub-níveis "país" e cada "país" tem números diferentes de sub-níveis também. O nível mais interno, onde tem "Valor 1", "Valor 2" e "Valor 3", é fixo. Cada um tem exatamente os 3 valores.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Você consegue nos fornecer um modelo invariável que descreva como os dados estarão organizados dentro desse array? Serve um esquema JSON ou outro tipo de esquema, mas que seja algo que defina com exatidão a estrutura 
 dos dados que serão modelados. Por que? O modelo que nos mostrou em PHP está enviesado pela linguagem, e já como percebeu C# é uma linguagem de tipagem estática ao contrario do PHP cujo a tipagem é dinâmica.

Comment: @augusto editei a postagem embora me pareça que não mudará muita coisa já que a estrutura JASON é praticamente a mesma coisa da array em PHP. De qualquer forma, agradeço o interesse.

Comment: Deixa eu tentar me fazer mais claro. É preciso saber os tipos, por exemplo `"Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3"` o que são cada um desses valores se são strings, se são inteiros, se são racionais de ponto flutuante ou outro tipo de dados. Como havia dito C# é uma linguagem de tipagem estática o que significa que  a estrutura que receberá esses dados será definida em tempo de compilação, o que é diferente do PHP onde a estrutura pode ser criada e alterada em tempo de execução.

Comment: PS: Mesmo que a pergunta acabe sendo fechada eu deixo uma resposta aqui nos comentários.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Desculpe, não pensei nessa questão pelo motivo da array estar declarada como string no C# e os "Valores" estarem entre aspas. Se fossem  valores numéricos, estariam sem aspas e a array precedida por int ou double ou algo assim. Apenas os dois níveis mais internos são int porque são muitas linhas por cada "pais". Alguns, chegam a quase mil linhas. Na representação em php e js, aliás, seriam:

Comment: $v1 = $mundo[oo][ns][pa][0][0];
$v2 = $mundo[oo][ns][pa][0][1];
$v3 = $mundo[oo][ns][pa][0][2];

ao invés de:

$v1 = $mundo[oo][ns][pa][0]["Valor 1"];
$v2 = $mundo[oo][ns][pa][0]["Valor 2"];
$v3 = $mundo[oo][ns][pa][0]["Valor 3"];

No caso do último [0], [1] e [2] de cada retorno, é índice numérico porque não coloquei associação, E acabei colocando "Valores..." para indicar que são strings.
Obrigado!

Answer (score -4):

Você pode usar classes, exemplo:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<Mundo> mundo = new List<Mundo>();

    Mundo mundoOri = new Mundo();
    mundoOri.nomeMundo = "ori";

    Pais pais = new Pais();
    pais.pais = "Pais 1";
    pais.valores.Add(new ValoresPaises() { valores = { "Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3" } });
    mundoOri.norte = pais;

    pais = new Pais();
    pais.pais = "Pais 2";
    pais.valores.Add(new ValoresPaises() { valores = { "Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3" } });
    pais.valores.Add(new ValoresPaises() { valores = { "Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3" } });
    mundoOri.norte = pais;

    pais = new Pais();
    pais.pais = "Pais 3";
    pais.valores.Add(new ValoresPaises() { valores = { "Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3" } });
    pais.valores.Add(new ValoresPaises() { valores = { "Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3" } });
    pais.valores.Add(new ValoresPaises() { valores = { "Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3" } });
    mundoOri.sul = pais;

    pais = new Pais();
    pais.pais = "Pais 4";
    pais.valores.Add(new ValoresPaises() { valores = { "Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3" } });
    pais.valores.Add(new ValoresPaises() { valores = { "Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3" } });
    mundoOri.sul = pais;

    pais = new Pais();
    pais.pais = "Pais 5";
    pais.valores.Add(new ValoresPaises() { valores = { "Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3" } });
    mundoOri.sul = pais;

    mundo.Add(mundoOri);

    Mundo mundoOci = new Mundo();
    mundoOri.nomeMundo = "oci";

    pais = new Pais();
    pais.pais = "Pais 6";
    pais.valores.Add(new ValoresPaises() { valores = { "Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3" } });
    mundoOci.norte = pais;

    mundo.Add(mundoOci);

}

public class Mundo
{
    public Mundo()
    {
        norte = new Pais();
        sul = new Pais();
    }
    public string nomeMundo { get; set; }
    public Pais norte { get; set; }
    public Pais sul { get; set; }
}

public class Pais
{
    public Pais()
    {
        valores = new List<ValoresPaises>();
    }
    public string pais { get; set; }
    public IList<ValoresPaises> valores { get; set; }
}
public class ValoresPaises
{
    public ValoresPaises()
    {
        valores = new List<string>();
    }
    public IList<string> valores { get; set; }
}
```